# Errors: XML validator says conetent not allowed in trailing section and other namespace issues?

Tags: xml, validation, namespaces, schema

I cannot for the life of me, figure out what is causing the errors in my XML file and schema. It should have just been an advanced schema that is for school, but days past the deadline, I cannot figure it out despite re-reading the chapter. Here are the errors I am getting:

> It was detected that 'sm:sites' is in namespace 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/ns', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'sm:sites' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added
>   1 Error
>
> Col 9 - Content is not allowed in trailing section. 1 Error

Here is the schema and XML:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:cc="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites/ns"
      targetNamespace="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites"
      xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/ns"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

 <xs:import namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
             schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" />

   <xs:element name="sites">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="site" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                     <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="totalPages" />
                     <xs:element ref="sm:sites" />
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>​
```

```xml
<sites xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites/ns"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites/ns sites.xsd">
    <site>
        <name>Weekend Fun Snacks</name>
        <totalPages>127</totalPages>
    <urlset xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/ns">
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=58</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=2</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-12-29T06:03:34+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=15</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-12-29T05:24:04+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=93</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=55</loc>
         </url>
      </urlset>
    </site>
    <site>
        <name>Paleo Snacks</name>
        <totalPages>52</totalPages>
    <urlset xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/ns">
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=6</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=18</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-09-19T17:13:19+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=54</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-09-19T15:24:01+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=52</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-09-28T21:03:11+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=201</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-10-06T07:03:26+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=11</loc>
         </url>
      </urlset>
    </site>
    <site>
        <name>Veg Snacks</name>
        <totalPages>17</totalPages>
     <urlset xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/ns">
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=102</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=23</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=1</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=55</loc>
            <lastmod>2017-06-12T08:05:32+00:00</lastmod>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=201</loc>
         </url>
         <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=87</loc>
         </url>
      </urlset>
    </site>
</sites>​​
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema, just change :

```
<xs:element ref="sm:sites" />
```

to

```
<xs:element ref="sm:urlset" />
```

This will refer to the appropriate element (namely `urlset`) you want to reuse- otherwise it means that you want to insert again the `<sites>` element.

Then in your XML, you need to change :

```
<urlset xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/ns">
```

to

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/ns">
```

And it should work fine. This is required because the `urlset` element you imported within your schema is bound to the the `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/ns` namespace. In the previous declaration, you bound the prefix `sm:` to the url, but it does not change the namespace of the element you are writing.

Comment: You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859980/ - I also answered to it.

Answer (score 2):

> Col 9 - Content is not allowed in trailing section. 1 Error

When you see an error like this, try to parse each document as XML. In this case, using `xmlparse` on your schema:

```
b:25: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
</xs:schema>​
            ^
```

Look at the end of that file in a binary editor:

```
0000000 003c 002f 0078 0073 003a 0073 0063 0068
0000020 0065 006d 0061 003e 200b
```

`U+003E` is the `>`. Then, you have a `U+200B` (zero-width space) at the end of your document. Your editor may not show it, but it's invalid XML.